# Can someone explain what this question is asking me? (Calculus II)

Tags: calculus

How to define the area of the region bounded by $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $y = 0$?

I am assuming we will be using Riemann's sum however I am not sure if we are given $[a,b]$ or is that what we are given?

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$ ??

Comment: When $y = 0$, what are the values of $x$? Is it possible for $y$ to be less than zero? Perhaps the answers to these give you a hint about the domain of integration. I suggest you draw a picture by plotting the graph of $f(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$.

Comment: Riemann's sum in Calculus II? Just find where $y=0$ and set up an integral.

Comment: When in doubt, plot it out and get a feel what the function looks like. If you type sqrt(1-x^2) into [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%281-x^2%29) (or even google), they will return you with a graph with a half circle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curves described are the upper half of the unit circle and the $x$-axis. So, the bounded component determined by these curves is the upper half of the unit disk. This region lies above the interval $[-1,1]$, since the two curves meet where $\sqrt{1-x^2} = 0$. This is at $x=\pm 1$, which determines the interval I mentioned.

In other words, $[a,b] = [-1,1]$, if you are asking what I *think* you are asking.

Comment: This will most likely sound "dumb", but just for clarification you get the range by setting the bounds we were given equal to each other? Just so I know what to do in the future. Also thank you for putting me in the right direction rather than just the answer.

Comment: In this case, yes. I set them equal to each other to see where they meet. This helps me draw the picture. You really *must* try to draw a picture to visualize what is going on. Then you can see from the picture that the interval in question is indeed the interval along the $x$-axis between the two points of intersection. BUT--don't just blindly set the functions equal to each other, that may or may not give you meaningful information. There is a definite reason I did that. Also, there could be several curves involved (not just two), so the picture is really the best guide to how you should go.

Comment: And this isn't a "dumb" question. That's what the forum is for. If you don't understand, or aren't sure, just ask (after you have tried something!), and be willing to explain your effort.

Comment: So if we were to step through this problem we would:

1: Find [a,b]
2: Find the limit of the Riemann sum of f(xi*)
3: Multiply that by the change in x?

Comment: I'm not sure what procedure you are using. Riemann sums generally limit to Riemann integrals. If you have two curves $y=f_1(x)$ and $y=f_2(x)$ and $f_1$ is always above $f_2$, then the area between the curves over the interval $[a,b]$ is $$\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\sum_i (f_1(x_i)-f_2(x_i))\Delta x = \int_a^b(f_1(x)-f_2(x))dx,$$ right? Here $f_1(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, $f_2(x) = 0$, and $[a,b] = [-1,1]$.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are superb at explaining this. I just had my exam and this helped me immensely.

Comment: I'm very glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The graph of $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ with range $0\leq y\leq 1$.

The region is exactly $\frac12$ of the total area of the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{Area} = \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx = \frac\pi2$$  Area of semi-circle of center the origin and radius $1$.

Comment: Use $\LaTeX$ but It'd be nice to tell OP where you got the $\pm 1$ bounds.

Comment: @Shahar It seems to be fairly obvious; the semi-circle is of radius one.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

the resultant area is the area inside the circle and above x-axis

so area is equal to $\pi r^2$/2 where r=1

and hence the area is $\pi$/2